# Не получается считать данные с файла.0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при записи по адресу 0x0014D000

Tags: c++, файловый-ввод-вывод

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct food
{
    char name[10];
    int kol;
    float price;
};
struct food shop[10];
void main()
{
    //setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    FILE* file;
    fopen_s(&file,"data.txt", "r");
    int i = 0;
    while (fscanf_s(file, "%s %d %f", &(shop[i].name), &(shop[i].kol),&(shop[i].price)) != EOF)
    {
        cout << shop[i].name << " " << shop[i].kol << " " << shop[i].price << " "<<shop[i].kol*shop[i].price<<endl;
            i++;
    }
    fclose(file);
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Уточните вопрос:  в каком месте происходит падение, в какой момент, что вы видите в отладчике и т. д.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще-то когда в `fscanf_s` - с `_s` - передается строка, надо указывать ее размер. Вы этого не делаете, происходит смещение аргументов.

Кстати, VC++ честно ругается на ваш код:

```
test.cpp(18): warning C4477: "fscanf_s": в строке форматирования "%s" требуется аргумент типа "unsigned int", но вариативный аргумент "2" имеет тип "int *"
test.cpp(18): note: этот аргумент используется в качестве размера буфера
test.cpp(18): warning C4477: "fscanf_s": в строке форматирования "%d" требуется аргумент типа "int *", но вариативный аргумент "3" имеет тип "float *"
test.cpp(18): warning C4473: "fscanf_s": передано недостаточно аргументов для строки формата
```

Разберитесь, какие аргументы следует передавать в [`fscanf_s`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/scanf-s-scanf-s-l-wscanf-s-wscanf-s-l?view=vs-2019).

Попробуйте примерно так:

```
FILE* file;
if (0 != fopen_s(&file,"data.txt", "r"))
{
    printf("Error open file\n");
    return 1;
}
int i = 0;
while (fscanf_s(file, "%s %d %f", &(shop[i].name), 10,
                &(shop[i].kol), &(shop[i].price)) != EOF)
{
```

Да, и `int main()`, а не `void main()`...

Comment: А, ой. Не заметил и сидел в тупняке. Спасибо большое